# Deserialize UUID using marshmallow

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am using marshmallow and sqlalchemy in my RESTful flask application to serialize and deserialize my models (It's my first time doing all of this). I have created a route to retrieve all users from a MySQL database. When querying the database, I am able to retrieve all the users (id, first_name, last_name). When printing out users, I see:

```
[
  ('UUID1', 'firstname1', 'lastname1'),
  ('UUID2', 'firstname2', 'lastname2')
]
```

**NOTE:** I store the ID as a binary and utilize the BIN_TO_UUID() and UUID_TO_BIN() database functions.

The response I get back when I hit this route is:

```
[
  {"first_name": "firstname1", "last_name": "lastname1"},
  {"first_name": "firstname2", "last_name": "lastname2"}
]
```

```
class UsersSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.UUID(attribute="id")
    first_name = fields.String()
    last_name = fields.String()

    class Meta:
        fields = ("id", "first_name", "last_name")

class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Binary(16), primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))
    last_name = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(255))

@app.route('/users')
def users():
    try:
        users = db.session.query(
            func.bin_to_uuid(Users.id),
            Users.first_name,
            Users.last_name,
        ).all()

    except Exception as e:
        print('we got an error in users route')
        print(e)
    finally:
        return jsonify(UsersSchema(many=True).dump(users))
```

Comment: Where did you get the`func.bin_to_uuid` function?  I can't find it in sqlalchemy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column in your query is probably not called `id` because of the `bin_to_uuid` function application. Then the Schema does not yield an `id` value because there is no such column. The solution should be to alias the first columnn in the query to `id`:

```
db.session.query(
    func.bin_to_uuid(Users.id).label('id'),
    Users.first_name,
    Users.last_name,
)
```

Comment: omg, you're a lifesaver!!!! I have been trying to solve this for soo long. Thank you so much and I appreciate it!